# How to conceal a mop outdoors to make it look aesthetically more pleasing?

Tags: cleaning, hardware, house-cleaning

I want to place a mop outside, but I don't want it to look like an eyesore.

How can one conceal a mop outdoors to make it look aesthetically more pleasing?

I would like the mop to take up as little room as possible.

The mop will be used every couple of weeks, so it needs to remain functional.  Urgent access to the mop is not a priority, as it won't be used for emergencies, but it shouldn't be a big ordeal just to use the mop.

I'm willing to use any type of mop.

Comment: You could make it look like the Venus de Milo. What could be more aesthetically pleasing than any kind of a mop? Maybe a number of different kinds arranged in a mop bouquet? Surely that would be aesthetically more (?) pleasing. Kindly add some necessary detail so that we can appreciate the need for a lifehack. I, for one, have some difficulty seeing any application, relevancy, or need. What am I missing?

Comment: Where outside do you want to place the mop? Are you in an urban, suburban, or rural location? Do you want immediate access to the mop? Is the mop ever used indoors? Must you own a mop or can you use a substitute? Does the appearance of any specific parts of a mop (such as a/the long handle) cause anxiety? Is the size of the mop inconvenient? Is the mop ever used with other problematic objects such as a pail?

Comment: Stand it in a nice plant pot, head down.

Comment: What about mop cabinet?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Interesting idea. I searched the Evil EmpireⓇ (Amazon), and the only mop cabinets I found cost 50-250 times the price of the actual mop.  Also, they take up a whole lot of space, which wouldn't be ideal.  Most of them would deteriorate quickly outdoors.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket what about a mop hook hidden behind a curtain?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think a curtain would likely have difficulty existing outside in the elements (rain, wind, etc.).

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: a picture of "your outdoors" would help a lot. Otherwise, just place it right next to the broom, like ordinary people do ;) And if you use it only sporadically anyway, why cannot you keep it inside, where it is hidden from unwanted eyes?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to point out that mops (and brushes) last longer and stay fresher if they are not resting on the business end. They spark more joy if you hang them up.

Our mops and brushes come with a hole drilled in the handle for putting a string through, and we hang them out of the way, e.g. behind a door. Out in the garden I would hang my mop out of sight, behind a large potted plant or next to the dustbins.

Or, decide it's not a bug but a feature. Decorate the shaft with paint or maybe a knitted cover. Then it will look good everywhere (depending on your taste).

Comment: Hi RedSonja.  There are 2 parts of your answer I really like.  The first is your wording of "spark more joy"... it simply made me smile. :)  The second is your idea to "convert the bug to a feature" and decorate the shaft.  That's a wonderful idea.  If I go this route, this trick will be to decorate it in a way that it will withstand the weather.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give me much to go on. Despite your dearth of detail, I lean toward a "one-way" mop disguise. I hope either of these two lifehacks satisfies your requirements for aesthetic in addition to nearly total anonymity to mop. Once disguised, the past mop is unrecoverable.

First, using a 'rope' mop, prepare a mix of acrylic and epoxy to create a sculpture. The mix will be stable for years. Find out more at [mop art](https://diyways.com/diy-paint-mop-art/)

[image: Preparation]

[image: Final mop art piece]

Maybe that is a bit much for your taste. Perhaps something that is more 'understated' that, at a casual glance, appears completely normal. More scrutiny over a while may reveal that the [standing mop dog sculpture](https://www.dogsinart.com/standing-mop-dog-sculpture-by-dominic-gubb-1/) by Dominic Gubb is in fact bogus.

[image: standing mop dog sculpture]

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder so I can't comment on the aesthetic achievement of the two suggestions insofar as you wanted.

Either of these can be placed outdoors and I might say they would be welcome by some indoors, too.

Good luck.

Comment: LOL.  Okay, yes, the mop actually has to be functional.  But maybe I can borrow that dog every couple of weeks. ;)

Comment: If you did that with dyes, instead of acrylic, it might work. As it is, the epoxy will make it unusable and even just the acrylic would wear off during use, making more of a mess. I do like the idea of putting color into it, though, just the method is questionable.